# maxflow-mincut theorem, why no augmenting path implies existence of maxflow

Tags: graph-theory, duality-theorems, network-flow

[image: maxflow-mincut theorem]
The proof is taken from course *Algorithm II, Princeton, coursera*. In the proof of iii => i, Why/How iii implies the existence of cut (A, B)?

Comment: A cut is a partition of the vertices into two disjoint subsets, say $A$, $B$. Here they are just defining such a partition; there is nothing to prove. So can you explain more where your confusion lies?

Comment: @Casteels What if such a cut don't exist?

Comment: Well what do you mean by "such a cut"? What about it are you unsure of? That $s$ is in $A$ and $t$ is in $B$?

Comment: @Casteels Sorry, let me try to clarify: Why "*there is no augmenting path with respect to f*" implies that I can define "*a cut (A, B) where A is the set of vertices connected to s by an undirected path with no full forward or empty backward edges*"? Is there a possiblity, when there is no augmenting path, you can't find such a cut (A, B)? For example, when all forward edges are full, and there is no backward edges.

Comment: no: you always place $s\in A$ since paths of length $0$ are counted here. But with regards to your question, that doesn't really matter. They are defining $A$ by some rule, so it is *some* subset of the vertices, and that (together with $V(G)\setminus A=B$) makes it a cut. The definition of $(A,B)$ has nothing to do with the hypothesis (iii). The hypothesis is used afterwards, e.g., to show that $t\in B$.

Comment: @Casteels I see! **paths of length 0 are counted here** is the answer I after! Thank you, please fill an answer with the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is being defined just as the subset of vertices satisfying the stated property. So there is nothing to prove about it: it simply exists. Now potentially it might be the empty set, but that (together with its complement $V(G)$) would still count as a cut. Having said that, it is *not* empty here as paths of length $0$ count, and so you will always at least have $s\in A$